Prefilled Google Form always adds 4 hours to the datetime object
I have a script that creates a prefilled form link for users to edit. There is a datetime question in that form that, no matter what I do, always seems to assume I'm in the UTC time zone instead of New York/UTC-4, as it's adding 4 hours to the prefilled datetime object. e.g., when the prefilled form is accessed, the datetime question is always 4 hours later than the actual input being supplied.
I've double-checked the time zone settings for the sheet as well as for the script, and they're both set correctly to US Eastern/New York. Is there any way to correct this without manually subtracting time from the datetime object before submitting the form answer?
  //Populate Timestamp
  formItem = formItems[0].asDateTimeItem();
  response = formItem.createResponse(new Date(data[1]));  //data[1] is a datetime string in UTC-4
  formResponse.withItemResponse(response);


Can you share more of the code or at least some sample data for the variable formItems and data? I cannot replicate your issue based on the current details that you have posted. As far as I know, the code snippet you posted does not have anything to do with the 4-hour difference issue that you have encountered.

Related question: Time zone settings in Google Apps Script inaccurate

new Date(data[1]) - //data[1] is a datetime string in UTC-4 Would you please provide an example of value assigned to "data[1]".
